# How to use OpenShift 3 Online environment variables for PHP?

Tags: php, openshift

I tried `getenv('OPENSHIFT_PHP_IP')` and `getenv('OPENSHIFT_PHP_PORT')` both of which returned `1` which I assume is wrong...

I can't find the documentation for OpenShift 3 Online, only OpenShift 2 is currently available.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do. If you want to access your PHP application, you can access if by the [automatic environment variables](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/environment_variables.html) for OpenShift 3. There are also environment variables that *you* can set to control the [PHP configuration](https://docs.openshift.com/online/using_images/s2i_images/php.html). Finally, I'm unaware of any PHP application where you have to set the IP address and Port to listen on, but if you need to, you should specify '0.0.0.0' and '8080' as the host and port respectively.

Here's a sample [Laravel PHP application](https://github.com/luciddreamz/laravel-ex) for you look at for inspiration.

Comment: Oh, I don't think I have the permission to listen on tcp://0.0.0.0:8080, it generates err log `do not have permission on line xxx tcp://0.0.0.0:8080`

Comment: `Warning: stream_socket_server(): unable to connect to tcp://0.0.0.0:8080 (Address already in use)`

Comment: Based on that last message, it sounds like your application is already listening in 0.0.0.0:8080. Are you able to post some of your application code, or just describe in more details what you're trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: I think 8080 is the default port it listens to, but if you want additional port, OpenShift Online does not allow you just open one. So I gave up and moved on to another service provider.

Comment: I'm sorry you moved to another service provider, however you can open multiple ports for access on OpenShift. The typical use case for this would be 1 port for http(s) traffic, and another port for ws(s) traffic. When you [create the *route*](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/routes.html#creating-routes) into your project, you can specify how those ports map to externally available ports.